# Project is not updated in sonarqube after scan

Tags: java, gradle, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I upgraded my sonarqube from 5.6 to 6.4 with plugins according to [sonarqube compability matrix](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Plugin+Version+Matrix). But after that errors such as [this one](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-findbugs/issues/86) started appear during `gradle` build. I set properties `sonar.java.binaries=**/build/classes` and `sonar.java.binaries=**/test/classes` and now build is successful, but project is not updated in sonarqube after scan.

Did anyone face with this issue? How can it be checked?

**UPDATE:** I removed the next parameters from `gradle.properties` and now it works fine:

```
systemProp.sonar.sources
systemProp.sonar.tests
systemProp.sonar.test.inclusions
systemProp.sonar.exclusion
```

Comment: It's a proprietary project, but I can include common statements:


Missing blame information for the following files:
...
This may lead to missing/broken features in SonarQube
Invalid character encountered in file for encoding UTF-8. Please fix file content or configure the encoding to be used using property 'sonar.sourceEncoding'
Classes not found during the analysis 
BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Comment: Anything interesting in the analysis logs?

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam only messages I provided above. But it should not corrupt anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have to clear existing sonar files (existing sonar files) from your work space and build you project again.

In your workspace sonar folder might be created which contain sonar file open that folder and remove all files present folder/files.

[image]

Comment: could you explain in more details: location of these dirs, etc

Comment: It's in the autogenerated target folder. I've added a picture here for you.